# ASP.NET Core/Razor Pages Cookie Consent, 'Context' Does not exist in current context

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, cookies, razor, cookieconsent

I have an ASP.Net Razor website, hosted on Azure. Setting up Cookie Consent Policy with this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-7.0.

However, I am getting an error here:

```
 var consentFeature = Context.Features.Get<ITrackingConsentFeature>();
```

The name 'Context' does not exist in current context. Everywhere I read implies it should just be available in my project, My page is in the shared folder, I am running ASP.Net Core 7.0. My full code is below:

```
@page
@model MYCompany.Pages.IndexPortalModel
@{
}

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features

@{
    var consentFeature = Context.Features.Get<ITrackingConsentFeature>();
    var showBanner = !consentFeature?.CanTrack ?? false;
    var cookieString = consentFeature?.CreateConsentCookie();
}

@if (showBanner)
{
    <div id="cookieConsent" class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        Use this space to summarize your privacy and cookie use policy. <a asp-page="/Privacy">Learn More</a>.
        <button type="button" class="accept-policy close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" data-cookie-string="@cookieString">
            <span aria-hidden="true">Accept</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <script>
        (function () {
            var button = document.querySelector("#cookieConsent button[data-cookie-string]");
            button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                document.cookie = button.dataset.cookieString;
            }, false);
        })();
    </script>
}
```

I tried just replacing it with HttpContext which got rid of the error but gets null on page load. I checked all articles and ChatGPT, everything indicates Context should just be available. I followed article exactly, adding to Program.CS, layout, etc, please help and thank you.

Comment: remove "@page
@model MYCompany.Pages.IndexPortalModel
@{
}" and I believe it should work.  "@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" should be the first line.

Answer (score 0):

> replacing it with HttpContext which got rid of the error but gets null
> on page load

this worked in my side.

The document asks you to create a partial view and using `Context`, we could see that it's `HttpContext` essentially.

[image]

I test in my side after replacing 'Context' with `HttpContext`.

[image]

```
@page
@model WebAppRazor.Pages.Clients.IndexModel
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features

@{
    var consentFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<ITrackingConsentFeature>();
    // var consentFeature = Context.Features.Get<ITrackingConsentFeature>();
    var showBanner = !consentFeature?.CanTrack ?? false;
    var cookieString = consentFeature?.CreateConsentCookie();
}

<div>
    @if (showBanner)
    {
        <div>@consentFeature.CanTrack</div>
        <div>@consentFeature.HasConsent</div>
        <div id="cookieConsent" class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            Use this space to summarize your privacy and cookie use policy. <a asp-page="/Privacy">Learn More</a>.
            <button type="button" class="accept-policy close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" data-cookie-string="@cookieString">
                <span aria-hidden="true">Accept</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <script>
            (function () {
                var button = document.querySelector("#cookieConsent button[data-cookie-string]");
                button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                    document.cookie = button.dataset.cookieString;
                }, false);
            })();
        </script>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: When switching to HttpContext, I get when loading page to indexmodel:

 System.NullReferenceException: '

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageBase.HttpContext.get returned null.

Comment: Hi @CJ-44 could you pls share a minimal sample for reproducing the issue and troubleshoot it? since the code following the document worked in my side...